# How to run the bind_param() statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make the following code work but I can't reach the `execute()` line.

```php
$mysqli = $this->ConnectLowPrivileges();
echo 'Connected<br>';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `tblStudents` WHERE `idStudent`=?");
echo 'Prepared and binding parameters<br>';
$stmt->bind_param('i', 2 );
echo 'Ready to execute<br>'
if ($stmt->execute()){
    echo 'Executing..';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error executing!';
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

The output that I get is:

```
Connected
Prepared and binding parameters
```

So the problem *should* be at line 5, but checking the [manual of `bind_param()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) I can't find any syntax error there.

Comment: Why not echo the error received to help debug it? I think echoing `$stmt->error` will get you the exact error mysql is complaining about.

Comment: I updated my question, because now I can't even run the following line after `bind_param()`! @Todd That is useful, important to have in mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When binding parameters you need to pass a variable that is used as a reference:

```
$var = 1;

$stmt->bind_param('i', $var);
```

See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Note that `$var` doesn't actually have to be defined to bind it. The following is perfectly valid:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $var);

foreach ($array as $element)
{

    $var = $element['foo'];

    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: +1, Amazing, do you have any reference for this fact? I never learned that :)

Comment: Yes, added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here it is just a simple explaination
declare a variable to be bind

```
    $var="email";
$mysqli = $this->ConnectLowPrivileges();
echo 'Connected<br>';

$var="email";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, lastname FROM tablename WHERE idStudent=?" LIMIT=1);
echo 'Prepared and binding parameters<br>';
$stmt->bindparam(1,$var);
```

Answer (score -7):

Your actual problem is not at line 5 but rather at line 1.
You are trying to use unusable driver.
While [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) does exactly what you want.

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `tblStudents` WHERE `idStudent`=?"
$stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array(2));
return $stm->fetch();
```

---

After all the years passed since this answer has been written, a new PHP feature emerged, called "argument unpacking". So, since version 5.6 you can pass a value into bind_param:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', ...[2]);
```

But still you have a trouble with getting your data back out of a prepared statement :)

Comment: If it's unusable, then why is there software out there built on it, working as expected?

Comment: because people are using it bluntly as old mysql ext, **keeps all the drawbacks and insecurity**

Comment: Drawbacks and insecurity, I agree with. "Unusable" is something else entirely.

Comment: Of course I haven't. I'm glad you know what I have and haven't got experience with. I'll let you get back to your high horse now