# How can I bind an argument to mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote the following code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$xxxxx= $date->getTimestamp(); 

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT text_content, text_duration, start_time from texts WHERE start_time > xxxxx order by start_time asc")) {

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

and now - how can I substitute the xxxxx with the starttime in the most efficient way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: this `MYSQL_ASSOC` is considered mixing as MySQL APIs btw.

Comment: this question is so unclear, now I can't even see outside my window and mud has better transparency.

Comment: Ok @Fred-ii- I know it might be funny, sorry for that, I'm just a very beginner with php.. All I want to do is to kept the current functionality of this code and use the variable $date in select query with returning the result as an json array, could you help me with that?

Comment: [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32976046/) suggests you're *probably* using PDO to connect with; I may be wrong, but we don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with, along with what your DB schema looks like. At this point in time, it's still anybody's guess. You'll notice that I didn't post an answer, because I knew that this question was already unclear. Therefore, I'll have to stay out of the loop for a while, or take it up with the others' answers. One of which may not be so "talkative" ;-)

Comment: It's actually independent question, don't look for any other clues before because that doesn't matter and should not affect my question here.. I'm using mysqli and I thought I could get help here, so yeah..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run the bind\_param() statement in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748254/how-to-run-the-bind-param-statement-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

$ts   = time();
$sql  = "SELECT text_content, text_duration, start_time from texts 
         WHERE start_time > ? order by start_time asc";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm still getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_result() on boolean` - what might be the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look into this:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
$date = new DateTime();
$xxxxx = $date->getTimestamp();

$sql = "SELECT text_content, text_duration, start_time from texts WHERE start_time > ? order by start_time asc";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $xxxxx);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Then use `json_encode` with your result:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how can I refer to the result later on when fetching it into json?

Comment: To make a good answer, it is not enough just to google the relevant manual page.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: This is not an award winning platform to win best award for good answer. The answer satisfies the original question's need.