# PHP prepared statement doesn't work with intval()

Tags: php, int, prepared-statement, converters

Please look my code:

```php
$insertStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (OrderID, OrderTrackingNumber, OrderTotal, CustomerID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insertStmt->bind_param("ssdi", $orderID, strval("Not Ship Yet"), $orderTotal, $userID);
if ($insertStmt->execute()) {
    $insertStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ordersproducts (OrderID, ProductID, ProductSold) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $updateStmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE products SET ProductQuantity = ? WHERE ProductID = ?");
    foreach ($orderedProducts as $orderedProduct) {
        $productQuantity = intval($orderedProduct->ProductQuantity) - intval($orderedProduct->ProductAddedQuantity);
        $insertStmt->bind_param("sii", $orderID, intval($orderedProduct->ProductID), intval($orderedProduct->ProductAddedQuantity));
        $updateStmt->bind_param("ii", intval($productQuantity), settype($orderedProduct->ProductID, "integer"));
        if ($insertStmt->execute() && $updateStmt->execute()) {
            if ($updateStmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                $isSuccefull = TRUE;
            } else {
                $isSuccefull = FALSE;
                break;
            }

        } else {
            $isSuccefull = FALSE;
            echo $insertStmt->error . " | " . $updateStmt->error;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

At the line of `$updateStmt->bind_param`, if I convert `$orderedProduct->ProductID` to int by `intval($orderedProduct->ProductID)`, the `updateStmt` will not work `($updateStmt->affected_rows = 0)`. However, I use `settype($orderedProduct->ProductID, "integer");` then it will work like a champ. And only this place gets that issue; others work very well.

Why?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: mine prepared statement is not working too.

Comment: @DorukAyar Mine work very well, but it behaves weirdly. I am not new with PHP, but this is the first time I got this ridiculous issue.

Comment: I really don't use MySQL too much, but I used for my first time, it didn't worked

Comment: follow my code, it works well.

Comment: `bind param` is working with references, so do `$productQuantity=intval($productQuantity)` before

Comment: basiclly you have only to run bind params once, and then only refill the variable that was used in bind_param. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748254/how-to-run-the-bind-param-statement-in-php

Comment: @JOUM Ok. good to know that. So why does that affect to the converted methods I use here?

Comment: `affect` if the functions needs a reference, then `ìntval()` for example, wont work, because it returns only a value, if you use a variable it can taken as reference. so if you change your code above that all bind_*  functions get variables, then you can move bind_* above foreach. After that refill the variable and `execute()` as often as needed to run a query with new values

Comment: @JOUM ok. I did change the param value with a reference variable and move the bind_param above the loop, but still got same issue. 
BTW, I just read the document on PHP page; inval() and settype() return the same value, and the way they work is similar. Lol. Don't know what's happening.

Comment: Holy cow. I moved the above code to my laptop, and it worked. Seem my php configuration on my desktop has some problems. hmmm!