# Using variables in mysqli bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a number of similar ( but not identical ) sql statements. The parameter types vary for each call and so I want to pass these as variables. Something like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param( $typeString, $parameter1, $parameter1 );
```

Where $typeString can be set to 'ss' or 'is' or 'ds'.

I get the error Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables.

I have tried (for instance)

```
$typeString = "is";
$typeString = "\'".$typeString."\'";
$stmt->bind_param( $typeString, $parameter1, $parameter1 );
```

And

```
$typeString = "is";
$stmt->bind_param( $typeString, $parameter1, $parameter1 );
```

But still get an error.

Is it possible to set this with a variable?

Comment: Where is the sql statment? And never bind a variable twice, you use `$parameter1` twice.

Comment: And you just only once bind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748254/how-to-run-the-bind-param-statement-in-php#15748384  then refill the parameter variables and execute again. And if possible use always `s` for param typ.

Comment: _number of similar ( but not identical ) sql statements_ so if you have 2 sql statements then you have also 2 mysqli stmt objects (for each stmt one). So nothing should mixed up here.

Comment: Not sure I get it. Do you want to *reuse* a prepared statement for *different* queries?

Comment: Nope here: reuse of bounded varaibles  _for different execution of the query_. And stmts are for multi execution made! Send it once to the sql server (query with placeholder), but execute it with diff parameter (only varialbes send to mysql).

Comment: Sorry for $typeString, $parameter1, $parameter1 read $typeString, $parameter1, $parameter2

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I was asking the OP. Perhaps he just means the *same* query although with differently typed parameters :-?

Answer (score 1):

1. First variant makes no sense as quotes shouldn't be sent into type definition list.
2. Second variant actually works.
3. There is little use in setting specific parameters. Just use 's' for everything.